# dojo datagrid 1.7 automatically updating when record in store changes

Tags: datagrid, dojo, store

I'm trying to find out the best way to get a datagrid to update when a record in a has a value changed.

I've tried using the observable store wrapper but this does not seem to make the datagrid update automatically.

I know that I can force the datagrid to refresh by calling grid.setQuery but it appears as if this would basically reload all the records into the datagrid again which seems overkill for a single record update.

Anyone know of a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you call myStore.notify() the observable store should push the update to the grid.